# Failed sharing my first file with BitTorrent

Tags: bittorrent

I read some tutorials, but for some reason, I can't download the file:

1. On the source PC (ie. the one that has the file I want to share), I launched uTorrent, chose File > Create New Torrent, and created the .torrent file.

FWIW, I later tried using [OpenBitTorrent](http://openbittorrent.com/) as the single tracker instead, but it made no difference.

For some reason, the file is displayed in the Downloading section, with nothing happening ("Downloading 0.0%"):
[image]

Why am I required to download a file that I already have, and why is nothing happening?

2. Uploaded the .torrent file to a web server
3. On a second host, launched uTorrent, and pasted the URL from the web server: It just says "Downloading 0.0%", with no action.

Looks like I'm missing something. Does someone have an idea what it could be?

Thank you.

Comment: the torrents need to be hosted at piratebay and meganova where you have the trackers listed, if you plan on hosting your own torrents you will have to set up a tracker server, otherwise upload them to one of a thousand torrent hosting sites like piratebay.

Comment: Doesn't uTorrent take care of connecting to the trackers and uploading  stuff there? The tutorials I read didn't specify I had to do anything more than this.

Comment: No, you have to go to the site and upload the torrent manually. Most require registration/membership before you can upload a torrent.

Comment: I added two trackers when creating the Torrent file, but I get the same result: uTorrent is waiting to download :-/ udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce
udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce

Comment: "PublicBitTorrent is a bittorrent tracker free for anyone to use. You don't need to register, upload or index a torrent anywhere, all you have to do is to include the PublicBitTorrent tracker URL in your torrent."

Comment: It's semi-working (d'loading through web browser) if I drag and drop the file I want to share in uTorrent's   "Drop files to send" section, and paste the TinyURL in the client, but I'd like to be able to share with any BitTorrent client, not just uTorrent.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is that both machines are behind NAT. The torrent protocol doesn't know they're both behind the same NAT and doesn't specially handle that case. It assumes a system behind NAT can't initiate a connection to any other system behind NAT. So if both ends are behind NAT, a connection is not possible.

If you want to set up a torrent seed behind NAT, you really need to set up port forwarding.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say I mapped a port on the NAT for the incoming connection needed by uTorrent.

Comment: To which machine? (And if your router doesn't support hairpin NAT, that would explain why you weren't able to download it. The mapping only works for incoming connections.)

Comment: I made sure PC #2 was connected to another network, although it doesn't have a port mapped (but as I understand it, it doesn't prevent downloading, only it's slower)

Comment: It finally worked with that tracker: udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce, although the client had to wait about 10mn for downloading to start.